# Delete character by character

Tags: javascript

i got a problem. I'm actually making a blog for myself and everything goes fine. But at a moment i wanted to do something cool with my inputs for login, so what if i could remove placeholder characters one by one ?

```
var run = 0;
var inte;
function removet(obj) {
    run = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(run > 8) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        else {
            stri = obj.placeholder;
            stri = stri.substring(0, stri.length - 1);
            obj.placeholder = stri;
            run++;
        }
    }, 22, obj);
}
```

And, IT WORKS !
... but. I got a little problem.
Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'" onfocus="removet(this)">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Password'" onfocus="removet(this)">
<button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
```

Deleting USERNAME works fine, but when i try that with password... The two are deleted at half. Why ? Where is my error ?

Comment: @Teemu I was just thinking the same thing, but with a less clear description in my head. Make that an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to not clear All Intervals

```
function removet(obj) {
    run = 0;
    var k= setInterval(function () {
        if(run > 8) {
            clearInterval(k);
        }
        else {
            stri = obj.placeholder;
            stri = stri.substring(0, stri.length - 1);
            obj.placeholder = stri;
            run++;
        }
    }, 22, obj);
}
```